# Javascript time function

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to use javascript in my webpage to print time such as

8:40 am

Mountain Time

How to modify the Date() function?

Comment: what have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

http://www.pageloom.com/automatic-timezone-detection-with-javascript